# Dimensions Zooming HTML/CSS Problems

Tags: html, css

I need help on http://fuzeshare.com/ (coded by me) the sidebar widget only appears on some monitors that have small dimensions. I cant seem to make it stay if I zoom in on my browser, since it disappears.

How do I make it not disappear upon zoom? Thanks
-Ry

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `right : 773px;` from `#sidebar`. After I think yoou should rewrote your html/css. Dor example, add a wrapper to your header (a `<header>` maybe ?) or remove the `<center>` tag.

Next time, can you add a jsfiddle too ?